# Can we define a custom validity period for active_model_otp?

Tags: ruby

I am using https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp for two way authentication during signup. The otp code would be sent to the user email address which he will enter in the first step and after entering the otp code he can set the password and continue.

Flow:

User Name, Email -> OTP code -> Password, Confirm Password

The current validity time of otp code is 30 seconds.

Can we increase this duration through this gem or any other way of doing it?

Comment: Please check tags before you link them. [tag:otp] has nothing to do with this question; removed.

Comment: [`ROTP`](https://github.com/mdp/rotp#preventing-reuse-of-time-based-otps) surely supports it, but your thin wrapper does not. You need to add the additional column to your table and manage it manually.

Comment: Thanks @AlekseiMatiushkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

Check this.
https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp#authenticating-using-a-slightly-old-code

```
user.authenticate_otp('186522', drift: 60) # => true
```

or even longer

```
user.authenticate_otp('186522', drift: 7.days.to_i) # => true
```